# "Unfortunately, the great old train didn't survive until the end of the century it was named for."

Tags: sentence-meaning, american-english

"Unfortunately, the great old train didn't survive until the end of the century."

can I rephrase it as "the old train didn't get through the end of the century?

Comment: You can, but your rephrase would be more informal.

Comment: Thank you and, actually you can post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but your two examples partially change the meaning of the sentence given as the title, "Unfortunately, the great old train didn't survive until the end of the century **it was named for**."

The title gives, indirectly, a name for the train, perhaps the [20th Century Limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20th_Century_Limited). Your two edited sentences lack that reference.

Comment: Got it, thanks a lot!